# changing white space character in IAR embedded

Tags: embedded, character, whitespace, workbench, iar

The white space character in IAR Embedded (I specifically use STM8 variant, don't know their ARM tools) is the most intrusive, compared with any other IDE we use (and there are many of them). If you enable "show white space", then a very BIG UGLY \cdot character appears instead of every space character, which makes your source code impossible to read.

Some other IDEs have much smaller/nicer/less intrusive characters (we love the "single pixel" from Keil's uVision, that's brilliant!) and in some other you can customize it, by either changing the character, or changing the foreground color of white space to make it more "pale" (and less intrusive, like in Notepad++, or PN). This may or may not work in comments (where the white space char takes the color of the comment, which is not nice, but we don't care about comments). In some other cases (like Notepad++, where you can change the foreground but not the character) we were able (after some help from this very forum, thanks!) to replace the big-cdot white space character by playing some "scintilla tricks" with the configuration. We applied that to eclipse later, too, and we are happy about that :D

None of it would work for IAR-EW IDE. One can not change the whitespace symbol, not are they able to change its foreground color to gray it out or so. At least, not in a convenient way, or not to our knowledge. Being able to see the white space is essential for our work (no joke, this is not subjective caprice, it helps a lot when coding too, but we are more stressed about editing big blocks of data). If we can solve this issue, we may even buy the toys from IAR :P. Right now we are using a 14-days trial, and we like it more than the "silly IDE" offered by ST for free, except that in both cases we have to edit our important files in Notepad++, where we can see the white space and also have the advantage of block-editing and multi-line simultaneous typing, and later copy/paste them into IAR-EW, to compile and debug. IAR seems quite unresponsive about it.

So, does anyone knows and likes to tell us if it is possible to change this character, and if so, then how?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Programmers often forget that they are programmers :) You could perhaps spend an hour of your time making a little tool which displays text files - and does nothing except displaying white space in your favorite way of formatting them. Then either find a way to conveniently run it from within the IDE or just let it run in the background.

Comment: Don't have to. There are plenty of tools doing that (Notepad++ was just discussed). And I am not really such a good "high level" programmer to make that in an hour. My expertise is "close to metal" C and assembler for x86/Atmel/Arm/Cortex/MCUs (writing firmware for industrial controllers for 40 years).

Comment: I am an embedded programmer too, for the most part, except a brief period of Windows programming. It's not rocket science to pick up some RAD tool and have it show formatted text, however. Can do it in C++ if that's more familiar than Java, .NET et al.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about STM version of EW, but in ARM version the color used for whitespace characters is the "Other" class.

That color seems to be shared with some other lesser used symbols such as some pragma values. So you probably don't want it turn it completely white-ish.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Unfortunately there is no "others" for IAR EW IDE STM8 3.11.1, which we use, it is ages old, but it looks like the last version - the company is not responsive and it seems they are not very interested in supporting these old MCUs anymore, now all the industry slowly switches to Cortex M :(

Comment: @LaurV Screenshots of STM8 version on IAR page look like the "face-lift" version of the IDE, similar to what ARM uses. It has file autorefresh, and when I use Notepad++ with that, there is no need to manually copy and paste between them. So I can do all editing in Notepad++ and debugging in IAR IDE.